Is it worth making a tag for [reproducible-builds]?
A search for "reproducible build" turns up 61 posts. Even if we discount some of the posts as questions and answers in the same thread, I think a reproducible-builds tag would be in the top half of tags by usage.
Is it worth making a tag to group them?

If you think that this is a useful tag, and something that would be filtered by, then by all means go for it - if you can define clearly what questions should be tagged with that, as the focus of the question and not a side mention.
